# How can I import python custom class in Anaconda (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, class, import, anaconda, jupyter

I don't manage to find how import custom class in Python with the Jupyter notebook in anaconda.

In my work folder I have a file **'user.ipynb'** that contains a class name **User**. In an other file in the same folder, I try to import this class with : **from user import User**.

I get this error: ImportError: No module named user.

I tried to create a file ' _ _init__.py' and _ _init__.ipynb in this folder but it doesn't work.

Do you know how I could do this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Put your class in a plain text file called "myclass.py". The Python interpreter won't be able to look inside your `.ipynb` file, AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works !

Answer (score 6):

Python modules are either files named `*.py` or directories with an `__init__.py` in them. `user.ipynb` is neither, it's an IPython (Jupyter) notebook, so it is not a module and you can't import it.

The easiest way to get this to work is to convert the notebook to a `.py` file (this can be done using the export function) and then you'll be able to import it.

An alternative is to provide code that lets you import notebooks directly; such code [is available here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb). Looks like a lot of bother, though. I'm not sure why they didn't just bake this in; it seems like it would be useful.

Comment: The dir of the `*.ipynb` file being executed is added to the Python path. You can check this in `sys.path`. So any Python module you define there is importable. If you want to use another dir you can add it to `sys.path`.