# Custom class in python not loading on jupyter notebook even though defined and imported appropriately

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, modulenotfounderror

This is my code for loading the Shirt class in jupyter notebook.

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count":  None,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "class Shirt:\n",
    "\n",
    "    def __init__(self, shirt_color, shirt_size, shirt_style, shirt_price):\n",
    "        self.color = shirt_color\n",
    "        self.size = shirt_size\n",
    "        self.style = shirt_style\n",
    "        self.price = shirt_price\n",
    "    \n",
    "    def change_price(self, new_price):\n",
    "    \n",
    "        self.price = new_price\n",
    "        \n",
    "    def discount(self, discount):\n",
    "\n",
    "        return self.price * (1 - discount)"
   ]
  }
```

I used `from shirt import Shirt` to import this class.

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-47eeb6b1d680> in <module>
----> 1 from shirt import Shirt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shirt'
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shirt'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import python custom class in Anaconda (Jupyter notebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346892/how-can-i-import-python-custom-class-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @rustyhu was wondering if you could provide a brief explanation. I did see this link, it's partially useful, but, my error hasn't resolved.

Comment: Why not put your `Shirt` class definition into a `.py` file to import?

Comment: @rustyhu I forgot to respond here but my issue was resolved. It was actually a compatibility issue, something I discovered after correcting the imports provided in your solution. Thank you :)